# Get rid of Jenkins and Hudson Manifest entry

Tags: hudson, manifest, maven-plugin, jenkins

I am getting below look like file in the MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: operations
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
Hudson-Build-Number: 158
Hudson-Project: my-dev
Hudson-Version: 1.421
Implementation-Build: rev 29299
Implementation-Version: 1.0-158
Jenkins-Build-Number: 158
Jenkins-Project: console-dev
Jenkins-Version: 1.421
Specification-Title: My Webapp
Specification-Vendor: nameit
Specification-Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

But I do not want below files to be injected, or I am not sure from where is this getting injected, my pom xml file has maven-war plugin with above argument mentioned excluding below entries.

```
Hudson-Build-Number: 158
Hudson-Project: my-dev
Hudson-Version: 1.421

Implementation-Version: 1.0-158
Jenkins-Build-Number: 158
Jenkins-Project: console-dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading to the latest version of jenkins. I am not seeing these manifest entries with version 1.441. Apparently I would like to have these entries auto populated by Jenkins. So if anyone can figure out a way to get that back in, it would be great.